# How do do fsi settings in Visual Studio Code to prevent print out

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, fsi

I am using lonide for f# with Visual Studio Code.

I would like to prevent the FSI output window to print out the defined code and variables. I learned that this can be done with a setting like this:

```
fsi.ShowDeclarationValues <- false
```

The question is, how do I do this setting in lonide fsharp extension for visual studio code?

Comment: I would expect the above to work - you might get errors in the editor saying `fsi` is not defined, but if you run it, it should still work.